# How to set width of a control inside a function for QUnit test?

Tags: sapui5, qunit

I have a scrollContainer which I need to set the width of. However, i'm not sure how to access the width inside my test file.

I can access the controller through

```
this.oViewStub = new Control()
var oScrollContainer = new sap.m.ScrollContainer() 
this.oViewStub.byId returns oScrollContainer <-- pseudocode
```

This is the code i'm trying to reach in my test file:

```
this.getView().byId("scrollContainer").$().parent().parent().width().
```

So I have this.getView().byId("scrollContainer") covered as it returns oScrollContainer but i'm unable to set/get the width of it. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a CSS file and define a class with the width that you want;
2) this.getView().byId("scrollContainer").addStyleClass("yourClass");
3) If it still doesn't work, probably the SAPUI5 standard code is overwriting your CSS. In this case you can specify a more precise path to reach your scroll container in the CSS file, but one thing that should work is to include the property !important when you set the with in your CSS file:

```
.yourClass {
    width: 7rem !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'm looking to add the width for the QUnit test, not the regular file.

Answer (score 0):

something like sinon.stub($.prototype, 'width').returns(900) will work